# Eclipse Tycho Target Platform "Set as Target Platform"

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, eclipse-pde, target-platform

Maybe this is a totally stupid question, but I need to ask it (directly and explicitly):

If I setup Tycho to use a target definition file, do I have to click on "Set as Target Platform" if something changes in the target platform (e.g. in the p2 sites)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Set as Target Platform" sets the target definition as target platform in your Eclipse workspace. It doesn't have any effect on the Tycho build.

As a general rule of thumb: Tycho does read configuration files like `MANIFEST.MF`, `*.target`, but it never reads Eclipse's workspace metafiles, like `.project`, `.classpath`, or anything from the projects' `.settings` or the workspace's `.metadata` folders.

Also, the Tycho build doesn't affect the Eclipse project and workspace configuration. So if there was a change in one of the p2 repositories referenced in the target definition, Tycho would automatically pick up this change in a build, but you still would need to click on "Set as Target Platform" to see the change in Eclipse.

Comment: Hey... thanks for the answer... Just to clarify it: That means in essence that everytime I build the "master" with its modules, that a "new" target platform will be configurated/set with the help of the .target file, right?! (hopefully I got it right, because otherwise I do not understand the tycho concept)

Comment: If you mean "set in the Eclipse workspace" then no. Tycho does the same build as Eclipse/PDE, but it doesn't interact with Eclipse in any way.